# External files with locale messages with a page in tapestry 5

Tags: localization, locale, tapestry

We are using Tapestry 5.4-beta-4. My problem is:

I need to keep files with locale data in an external location and under different file name then tapestry usual app.properties or pageName_locale.properties. Those files pool messages that should be then used on all pages as required (so no tapestry usual one_page-one_message_file). The files are retrieved and loaded into tapestry during application startup. Currently i am doing it like this:

```
@Contribute(ComponentMessagesSource.class)
public void contributeComponentMessagesSource(OrderedConfiguration<Resource> configuration, List<String> localeFiles, List<String> languages) {
    for(String language: languages){
        for(String fileName : localeFiles){
            String localeFileName = fileName + "_" + language + ".properties";
            Resource resource = new Resource(localeFileName );
            configuration.add(localeFileName, resource, "before:AppCatalog");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works in that the message object injected into pages is populated with all the messages. Unfortunatly these are only the messages that are in the default ( first on the tapestry.supported-locales list) locale. This never changes.

We want the locale to be set to the browser locale, send to the service in the header. This works for those messages passed to tapestry in the traditional way (through app.properties) but not for those set in the above code. Actually, if the browser language changes, the Messages object changes too but only those keys that were in the app.properties are assigned new values. Keys that were from external files always have the default values.

My guess is that tapestry doesn't know which keys from Messages object it should refresh (the keys from external files ale not beeing linked to any page). 
Is there some way that this could be solved with us keeping the current file structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you add the language (locale) to the file name that you contribute to ComponentMessagesSource.

For example if you contribute

```
example_de.properties
```

Tapestry tries to load

```
example_de_<locale>.properties
```

If that file does not exist, it will fall back to the original file (i.e. example_de.properties).

Instead you should contribute

```
example.properties
```

and Tapestry will add the language to the file name automatically (see MessagesSourceImpl.findBundleProperties() for actual implementation).

```
@Contribute(ComponentMessagesSource.class)
public void contributeComponentMessagesSource(OrderedConfiguration<Resource> configuration, List<String> localeFiles, List<String> languages) {
    for(String language: languages){
        for(String fileName : localeFiles){
            String localeFileName = fileName + ".properties";
            Resource resource = new Resource(localeFileName );
            configuration.add(localeFileName, resource, "before:AppCatalog");
        }
    }
}
```